# What does node.js mean for Nightwatchjs?

Tags: node.js, nightwatch.js

I have been using `Selenium`, `Testng`, `Java`, `Maven` to automate browser and I know these compliment each other. We can use one tool's method (APIs) in with other.

Now I have to automate using `Nightwatch.js`. During its initial setup I was asked to install `node.js`, but never got to know that why I need it? Why an installation of `Nightwatch.js` itself not enough?

I have tried to find out on `Nightwatch`'s official page, but couldn't find out. Seems I am asking a very basic, foundation level question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a Nutshell:

NodeJS is a Javascript runtime that runs on the server. It is built on V8, Google's Javascript engine. This is the equivalent of the JVM and the Java Platform.

`npm` is a very popular package manager for the Javascript world and it is tighly integrated with Node. This is probably on the `npm` repositories that you will download `Nightwatch.js`. This is the package manager part of Maven for Javascript.

`Nightwatch.js` is a Node library that wraps Selenium for use in a Javascript environment. It is also a test runner, like JUnit or TestNG are for Java.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey, man nicely explained. The best part is comparing it with Java and providing its JS counterpart.